# What endpoint is typically used to get a Token Price on Quipuswap or what is the standard method to get a Token Price

Tags: transactions

What endpoint is typically used to get a Token Price on Quipuswap or what is the standard method to get a Token Price? I just need to know where to start with pulling charting data from Tezos Exchanges.

Comment: Afaik there is no endpoint to get a token price, you must calculate the price to get the current price at a certain time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any existing endpoint to grab the prices directly, so i use tzkt api to grab the LP contract storage (quipu v1) or the pairs big_map (306111) in QuipuSwap Dex Core 2.0 contract (KT1J8Hr3BP8bpbfmgGpRPoC9nAMSYtStZG43), the key being the bucket's pair id.

With this data you can calculate the spot price.

**Examples**

$uno (Quipu v1 LP): https://api.tzkt.io/v1/contracts/KT1Cq3pyv6QEXugsAC2iyXr7ecFqN7fJVTnA/storage

$uno (Quipu v2 LP):
https://api.tzkt.io/v1/bigmaps/306111/keys?key=94&select=value

**Note:** Dmitry from Baking Bad team wrote this one month ago (May 12th):

> Hi! We don't have any public API for 3route, but the token prices
> feature in our backlog for TzKT

Comment: Now that I think of it a second time, I think TzStats has a price endpoint but in its paid plan.

Comment: Crunchy has a very useful graphql api from their dex indexer. Just not sure we should use it directly. I would be happy with 4requests p/second :) Address can be found in their github repo.